# How to print multiple lines of aestricks (or any symbols) in R?

Tags: r

I just want to print multiple lines of aestrick symbols while running the code. I can use `print(strrep("*",20))` to print one line of 20 `*`'s, but how can I print 20 lines of these without using any loops?

Comment: `rep(strrep("*",20),20)` gives you 20 strings of 20 chars each. If you need them on individual lines, what about `cat(paste(rep(strrep("*",20),20),collapse="\n"))`?

Comment: @r2evans This works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal "how do I repeat" is shown here:

```r
rep(strrep("*",5),4)
# [1] "*****" "*****" "*****" "*****"
```

If you are intending up-front to print all of these sequentially on the console, then

```r
paste(rep(strrep("*",5),4), collapse="\n")
# [1] "*****\n*****\n*****\n*****"
cat(paste(rep(strrep("*",5),4), collapse="\n"))
# *****
# *****
# *****
# *****
```

where the latter `cat`s it directly. Note that `cat` does not add a last newline; if you need it, then do `cat(..., "\n")`.

You might consider using `message` instead of `cat`, however:

```r
message(paste(rep(strrep("*",5),4), collapse="\n"))
# *****
# *****
# *****
# *****
```

It doesn't require the trailing newline as `cat` does (though you can suppress the trailing LF with `appendLF=FALSE`). This allows anybody using your function to suppress these messages with `suppressMessages(...)`, often a nice consideration in function-authors.

Answer (score 1):

This might help. The function will print any number of lines you want.

```
  fun<-function(x){
  rep(paste(strrep("*",20),sep = "\n"),x)}

  fun(20)
```

For just 20 times you could use:

```
rep(paste(strrep("*",20),sep = "\n"),20)
```

Hopefully that helps.